# Rails 3, devise authorize and remote forms

Tags: ajax, ruby-on-rails-3, devise

I'm developing my first Rails application and it has Posts that can be commented. Inside the Post show page there is a comment button that loads the comments form (from comments/new.js.erb) and the user can submit the comment (using comments/creating.js.erb).

Anyone can see the Post show page, but only logged users can comment. Everything works fine when the user is already logged in, the problem is when he is not, because the Ajax call returns a 401.

My question is: how can request the devise login form in that case and, after the login, redirect the user back to the Post show page and trigger the ajax action?

I want to create more actions on this page that also need login to be performed, such as rating, but I couldn't find a solution yet.

Thanks!